# Android - How can I open an AlertDialog on a button click with DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

So I created a `DialogFragment` .java file to display my Alert Dialog. I used the tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) to create an AlertDialog with a list.

How can I reference this fragment in my ContactList.java file? What I understood to be the way to do this from the tutorial didn't seem to work. When I'm trying to do the onClick event using the code below in my ContactList.java file, I get a red squiggly under `getSupportFragmentManager()`.
Here's the code I have for the fragment:

```
public class StatusDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.choose_status);
    builder.setItems(R.array.status_choices,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Here's my relevant ContactList.java file code:

```
public class ContactList extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_list);
    Intent intent = getIntent();


}
public void chooseStatus(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new StatusDialogFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "statuschoice");
}
```

Lastly, here's the XML code for my button that I want to open the dialog.

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/status"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/status_available_icon"
    android:onClick="chooseStatus" />
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend the compatibility class [`FragmentActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) if you're coding for platforms below 3.0:

```
public class ContactList extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
```

If not, change `getSupportFragmentManager()` to `getFragmentManager()`

Also make sure that if you're using `FragmentActivity`, that your `StatusDialogFragment` extends the compatibility [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html) from the support package.

And if not (meaning you're only targeting 3.0+), make sure that the `DialogFragment` class you extend from is **not** from the support package.

Comment: how do you maintain the alertdialog on rotation?

Comment: @Maxrunner I don't know about `Dialogs` themselves since I use `DialogFragments` because they are kept on rotation.

Comment: Are you sure? i think you need to set retaininstance?

Comment: My implementations don't use retaininstance.

Comment: I also use dialogfragments but there's a setretaininstance in the oncreate

Comment: @Maxrunner Interesting. I don't know why our implementations differ though.

Comment: you use what? saveInstanceState and restoreInstanceState?

Comment: @Maxrunner Yeah. Although if it is a simple AlertDialog with a text message, that's not needed.